# Python Zelle graphics on Mac - `win.close()` will not work

Tags: python, macos, python-3.x, zelle-graphics

Using a Mac, win.close() is a statement from Zelle graphics I have never got to work. It has never closed any window when I have tried it in a code.
Does anyone know about a place I can ask, or where to send a question?

```
# test of win.close() from program
from graphics import *

def main():
    win = GraphWin()
    win.close()

main()
```

The problem is "found". win.close() works in Pycharm and if it is started from an OSX terminal window. But not from Idle run on OSX.

Answer (score 0):

In the program you've written, the window will open and then close immediately.
Try:

```
from graphics import *

def main():
    win = GraphWin()
    win.getMouse
    win.close()

main()
```

This will wait for a mouse click before closing the window. Hope this helped! ;) Let me know if you still have issues.

Comment: Hi, Thanks.
I believe I have "discovered" the problem:
There is something between graphics.py, Idle and Mac.
win.close() works in Pycharm, or if I start the program from an OSX terminal window.
But thanks for your answer :-)